# virtualenvwrapper message on every new terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I never tried to uninstall [`virtualenv` or `virtualewrapper`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) nor touched the directory. Both were installed through `apt`. When I open the `terminal` this message appears at the top:

```
bash: /home/name/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

Comment: On a terminal run `nano ~/.bashrc` to edit that hidden file, which run every time you open a terminal. Search for the line calling `virtualenvwrapper.sh` and comment it out with a `#`.

Comment: There is two called virtalenwrapper. Is source /usr/share/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper.sh or 
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

Comment: The message you post suggest the path of the second one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Pablo's answer, 
Running `nano ~/.bashrc` and putting `#` to comment out `source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`. Made the message go away in the terminal.